# Traefik self-signed certificate does nothing (no errors)

Tags: traefik

I have a working self-signed certificate of the host: local.whoami.com. I want to expose the dummy "whoami" service on both http and https protocols.

```
#docker-compose.yml

version: '3.6'

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command:
      - --api
      - --docker
      - --logLevel=INFO
      - --defaultentrypoints=http,https
      - --entryPoints=Name:http Address::80
      - --entryPoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS:/certs/local.whoami.com.crt,/certs/local.whoami.com.key
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./config/cert:/certs/

  whoami:
    image: emilevauge/whoami
    labels:
      traefik.backend: whoami
      traefik.frontend.rule: Host:local.whoami.com
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.protocol: http
      traefik.frontend.passHostHeader: true
```

Running `docker-compose up` succeeds without any errors:

```
whoami_1   | Starting up on port 80
traefik_1  | time="2018-07-26T14:36:41Z" level=info msg="Traefik version v1.6.5 built on 2018-07-10_03:54:03PM"
traefik_1  | time="2018-07-26T14:36:41Z" level=info msg="Preparing server http &{Address::80 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc420764620} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
traefik_1  | time="2018-07-26T14:36:41Z" level=info msg="Preparing server https &{Address::443 TLS:0xc420314800 Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc420764700} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
traefik_1  | time="2018-07-26T14:36:41Z" level=info msg="Preparing server traefik &{Address::8080 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] WhiteList:<nil> Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc4207647c0} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
traefik_1  | time="2018-07-26T14:36:41Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider {\"Watch\":true,\"Filename\":\"\",\"Constraints\":null,\"Trace\":false,\"TemplateVersion\":2,\"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate\":false,\"Endpoint\":\"unix:///var/run/docker.sock\",\"Domain\":\"\",\"TLS\":null,\"ExposedByDefault\":true,\"UseBindPortIP\":false,\"SwarmMode\":false}"
traefik_1  | time="2018-07-26T14:36:41Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :80"
traefik_1  | time="2018-07-26T14:36:41Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :443"
traefik_1  | time="2018-07-26T14:36:41Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :8080"
traefik_1  | time="2018-07-26T14:36:41Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :80"
traefik_1  | time="2018-07-26T14:36:41Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :443"
traefik_1  | time="2018-07-26T14:36:41Z" level=info msg="Server configuration reloaded on :8080"
```

I can successfully see the dummy service on http://local.whoami.com, but when accessing the secure https://local.whoami.com, nothing happens. Simply no response from traefik, and chrome shows:

> This site can’t be reached local.whoami.com
>
> took too long to respond.

Why doesn't the self-signed certificate work? How to trace the problem in the absence of any error?

Answer (score 0):

While using Docker on a VirtualBox machine, I had to add a port-forwarding rule also for port 443. That solved my issue. Hope it helps.